# How can I remove wallpaper and use just one color background in the new Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: customization, desktop-background

In the new ubuntu 12.04 can we have no wallpaper, just one plain background color?
In all the hundreds of systems I have know it is very easy to set a plain black background.
Why is ubuntu doing this things so difficult?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the attached image for this : [image]

In the appearance settings, there is drop down menu at the right top from where you can choose what sort of a background you want.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you. It is so hidden!! But it is very difficult to change the colors because if you don't do it exactly and want to correct it, then you have to start over again and again.

Comment: It changes immediately. Just minimize this application to see the effect.

Comment: It is difficult to change the color, you have to start over from the default